# Ember.JS insertNewLine not working

Tags: ember.js

Just started using Ember.JS so I apologize if this at all a stupid question. I have this in my `app.js` file:

```
window.Todos = Em.Application.create();

Todos.Todo = Em.Object.extend({

    title: null,
    completed: false

});

Todos.todosController = Em.ArrayController.create({
    content: [],

    createTodo: function(title)
    {
        var todo = Todos.Todo.create({title: title});

        this.pushObject(todo);
    }
});

Todos.CreateTodoView = Em.TextField.extend({

    insertNewLine: function()
    {
        alert('test');
        var value = this.get('value');

        if (value)
        {
            Todos.todosController.createTodo(value);

            this.set('value', '');
        }
    }
});
```

Then this in my `index.html` file:

```
 <script type="text/x-handlebars">
   {{view Todos.CreateTodoView id="new-todo" placeholder="What needs to be done?"}}
 </script>
```

I believe `insertNewLine` is meant to be called when you press enter in the text box, am I right? The textbox renders fine but whenever I press enter it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `insertNewline`. Note the *lowercase* **l**. With it works as expected. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WfXvq/).